# 36-bit hex DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime, hex

I have the following known pair of hex values and dates:

```
"0c133314002a" = "2017_08_24_12_52_00"
"0d1333140002" = "2017_08_24_13_02_00"
"0d133314000c" = "2017_08_24_13_12_00"
"0d1333141b10" = "2017_08_24_13_21_30"
```

I can't find a way to get from one to the other,

0d1333141b10 converts to binary like this "11010001001100110011000101000001101100010000"
but I don't see any way that binary then becomes a DateTime.

Comment: `0d133314000c` is 36 bits, not 12

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Fixed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out, the hex was obfuscated and mixed up.

```
string StupidDate = "0d1333141b10";

string p1 = "0" + Helpers.ArbitraryToDecimalSystem(StupidDate.Substring(6, 2), 13);
if (p1.Length == 3) { p1 = p1.Substring(1, 2); }
string p2 = "0" + Helpers.ArbitraryToDecimalSystem(StupidDate.Substring(2, 2), 5);
if (p2.Length == 3) { p2 = p2.Substring(1, 2); }
string p3 = "0" + Helpers.ArbitraryToDecimalSystem(StupidDate.Substring(4, 2), 7);
if (p3.Length == 3) { p3 = p3.Substring(1, 2); }
string p4 = "0" + Helpers.ArbitraryToDecimalSystem(StupidDate.Substring(0, 2), 17);
if (p4.Length == 3) { p4 = p4.Substring(1, 2); }
string p5 = "0" + Helpers.ArbitraryToDecimalSystem(StupidDate.Substring(10, 2), 21);
if (p5.Length == 3) { p5 = p5.Substring(1, 2); }
string p6 = "0" + Helpers.ArbitraryToDecimalSystem(StupidDate.Substring(8, 2), 19);
if (p6.Length == 3) { p6 = p6.Substring(1, 2); }

string DateString = "20" + p1 + "_" + p2 + "_" + p3 + "_" + p4 + "_" + p5 + "_" + p6;
```

The ArbitraryToDecimalSystem is from here: http://www.pvladov.com/2012/07/arbitrary-to-decimal-numeral-system.html